# Easier(better) way to write LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `LINQ` queries, I use the results of the 1st `LINQ` query and use a foreach loop to iterate through each element found and use it in the 2nd `LINQ` query

```
var entries = dbo.OnDemand.Where(c => c.LOTNO == LotNo).Where(c => c.ODHisDate >= start && c.ODHisDate <= end).Where(c => c.Activity.Contains(reprinted)).OrderBy(c => c.ODHisDate);

foreach (var X in entries)
{  
    Barcodes.Add(X.Barcode);    // Barcodes is a List<string>
}

foreach (string barcode in Barcodes)
{
    var entries2 = dbo.OnDemand.Where(c => c.Barcode.Contains(barcode)).Where(c => c.ODHisDate >= start && c.ODHisDate <= end).OrderBy(c => c.ODHisDate);

    // Do stuff with entries2
}
```

Is there a way I could execute this using a single query?

I read around, and people use `JOIN` but I am not entirely sure how to use it.

Some of the expressions are common for both queries (the selected date range, and the `ORDERBY` by date)

Currently this way works but I think there is a better way of doing what I am trying to achieve.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

Sample SQL query:

```
select * FROM [dbo].[OnDemand]
where barcode in
(
SELECT [Barcode]      
  FROM [dbo].[OnDemand]
  group by barcode
  having count(*) > 1
  )  
 and odhisdate between  '2017-01-11' and '2017-01-31' 

 and Activity like '%reprinted%'

  order by ODHisDate asc, ODHisTime asc
```

Comment: Could you explain a little the logic here?

Comment: Models would help.

Comment: @octavioccl - With the first query I get a list of barcodes that match the criteria. In the second query I get entries based on the each barcode

Comment: You should make your code as easy to debug as possible. Having a long linq statement would make it very difficult to debug since when you have an error in one of those statements, the stack trace only shows you the first line of those linq chain (i.e it would say line 1 even though the problem occurred in line 4). I'd suggest either having those condition checks in a select statement and having that select statement as a separate function or doing it one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're doing this because there are elements with the same barcode. A solution could be:

```
var entries = dbo.OnDemand.Where(c => c.LOTNO == LotNo 
                                   && c.ODHisDate >= start && c.ODHisDate <= end 
                                   && c.Activity.Contains(reprinted))
                          .Select(c => c.Barcode);//Don't need to orderby here

// You will get a IEnumerable<List<OnDemand>> as result of this query
var entries2 =entries.Select(barcode =>  dbo.OnDemand.Where(c => c.Barcode.Contains(barcode) 
                                                              && c.ODHisDate >= start && c.ODHisDate <= end)
                                                     .OrderBy(c => c.ODHisDate)
                                                     .ToList());

foreach (var list in entries2)
{
 // do stuff
}
```

Better Idea could be filter first by the common conditions, later group by barcode and then keep those groups who have an element that meets the second where conditions

```
var entries = dbo.OnDemand.Where(c.ODHisDate >= start && c.ODHisDate <= end)
                          .GroupBy(c=>c.BarCode)
                          .Where(g=>g.Any(c=>c.LOTNO == LotNo && c.Activity.Contains(reprinted) ))
                          .Select(g=>g.OrderBy(c => c.ODHisDate).ToList());
```

### Update

```
var entries = dbo.OnDemand.Where(c.ODHisDate >= start && c.ODHisDate <= end && c.Activity.Contains(reprinted))
                          .GroupBy(c=>c.BarCode)
                          .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
                          .Select(g=>g.OrderBy(c => c.ODHisDate));
```

Comment: yes you are right there are elements with the same barcode, I am trying to display information when reprinted barcodes are found. I also removed the `orderby` in the first query

Comment: your query in your edit is different and simplifies the problem

Comment: I was using that query in the SQL server management studio for testing,  but I don't know how to write it in C#

Comment: No I haven't tried it yet. I'll try it when I get the chance and let you know the result

Comment: I modified your updated query and now it works. Thanks for your help. Thanks to @bc004346 for suggested answer

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, there is no need for a `JOIN` because you are querying the same table and you are not trying to do a recursive or cross-join query.

Why do you query the same table with the same parameters? You get a `List` of entries back, then iterate through `Barcode` values and then go back again and query the same table with the same `Barcode` value.

If you want to iterate in-line, the syntax is straight forward, but I am not sure if you understand what you are doing there.

```
dbo.OnDemand.Where(c => c.Barcode.Contains(barcode))
    .Where(c => c.ODHisDate >= start && c.ODHisDate <= end)
    .OrderBy(c => c.ODHisDate)
    .ForEach(c =>
        {
            // do stuff
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on your answer?

Comment: I won't know the barcodes until I run the first query. So I don't think I can use `.Where(c => c.Barcode.Contains(barcode))` but I'll try it

Comment: Do you have a sample SQL query? What you do is get all barcodes, then iterate through the barcodes that you just got and query the same table again? Why would you want to do that? At this point, barcodes don't even make any difference to you: what you get back you query again... with the same parameters. I simply take your query and do an in-line iteration on it.

Comment: I have added a sample SQL query which I used for testing